# Images get uploaded itself from the computer

Tags: plugins, images

I have a lot of images in my computer and I want to upload them to my website. For that I am looking for some automated plugin in which I can copy those images and it would upload them itself. Is there any Wordpress plugin that does it?

### EDIT

To clearify what I want to achieve is,

**When I drag and drop images to the FTP in a folder, all of those images get posted itself.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd probably want to rephrase your question... Do you want each image to create a new post and be attached to it? Otherwise, it's simply a matter of dropping them all in the Upload New Media window `/wp-admin/media-new.php`

Comment: What is a lot? If it really is a lot you shouldn't be using http.

Comment: @brasofilo: I would like each of them to be treated as a different post.

Comment: @toscho: I have tried to find such a plugin but was unable to find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin does a batch upload and creates a new post/page/cpt from each file

[Fuxy's WP Images 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/images-2-posts/screenshots/)

You would only achieve the "*Images get uploaded itself from the computer*" if you make a custom script (Automator in Macs, don't know in Windows...) that would run in your OS and do that for you...

But, I don't have any suggestion for the "auto upload" trick, neither on how to connect that with a plugin... seems quite an ultra advanced task...

Comment: Thanks for that. I am looking towards more automated plugins.